# cloudera-scm-server is dead and pid file exists

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, cloudera

I am new to Ubuntu and Cloudera as well. I have installed Cloudera manager (5.7.1) on Ubuntu 14.04 from the [documentation](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/cm_ig_install_older_cm5.html#cmig_topic_6_6_1) given on Cloudera site. I am not able to connect to http://localhost:7180 . I checked the status of **cloudera-scm-server** by using `sudo service cloudera-scm-server status` command.

It was **cloudera-scm-server is dead and pid file exists** so I restarted the **cloudera-scm-server** after deleting the file. After restart server was showing status running. Then I again tried to connect to http://localhost:7180. As soon as I did that server status again changed to **cloudera-scm-server is dead and pid file exists**.

Can someone help me figuring it out? Thanks in advance

Edit:

I found this output for command

```
tail -f /var/log/cloudera-scm-server/cloudera-scm-server.out
```

> ... 34 more
>   Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Unable to locate the Cloudera Manager log file in the log4j settings
>       at com.cloudera.server.web.cmf.logs.LogUtil.getServerLogfile(LogUtil.java:34)
>       at com.cloudera.server.cmf.log.components.ServerLogFetcherImpl.(ServerLogFetcherImpl.java:77)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>       at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:126)
>       ... 36 more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following, i was able to fix the same issue:

```
$sudo rm /var/run/cloudera-scm-server.pid
$sudo service cloudera-scm-server-db stop
$/etc/rc.d/init.d/postgresql restart ----------------> Fixed in this or($/etc/init.d/postgresql restart in Ubuntu)
$sudo service cloudera-scm-server-db start
$sudo service cloudera-scm-server start
```

Let me know if this works for you, or else i'll suggest some other solution.

Comment: Thank you for your response but this solution is not working.

Comment: Ok let's try with this now:

Since there is a .pid file, remove it first.  Check the following and delete if it exists:

/var/run/cloudera-scm-server.pid

Next, if there is a problem starting, there are likely valuable clues in the logs.  Check out /var/log/cloudera-scm-server/cloudera-scm-server.log


Perhaps tail -f /var/log/cloudera-scm-server/cloudera-scm-server.log while starting to see if there are any exceptions.


If the solution is not obvious, post the details and someone here can help.

Comment: I have made changes in my question.

Answer (score 1):

Check the following and delete if it exists:

```
    /var/run/cloudera-scm-server.pid
```

Next, if there is a problem starting, there are likely valuable clues in the logs.  Check out /var/log/cloudera-scm-server/cloudera-scm-server.log

Perhaps tail -f while starting to see if there are any exceptions.

Or

If the above step doesn't fix your issue then the postgresql  is not running to identitfy it try to run command

**$service postgresql  restart**

if above command fails then you have to check in /etc/hosts if loopback address is missing 127.0.0.1 localhost

Add line 127.0.0.1 localhost save it, then try starting the postgresql service

**$service postgresql  start**

Hope this will help

Comment: Check on Cloudera Manager Server log file /var/log/cloudera-scm-server/cloudera-scm-server.log that will help to understand the RCA